# What features for Android development are missing in Intellij9 compared to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

Besides a drag-and-drop UI designer are there any other missing features when developing for Android?  Does anybody have suggested plugins for Android development in Intellij 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'drag-and-drop' the experience is more like immediately getting to see what the layout will look like without having to launch your app to the phone. This doesn't work very well for many of my layouts anyway.

I'd say by not using eclipse you aren't missing out on anything.

Comment: I find this a bit confusing, is there some real-time preview of the UI I've managed to miss?  When I looked at an XML Android UI markup file I just had code-completion of the XML, no preview.  If this is the case you just made my day, week, and perhaps month.

Comment: Inside the Android Eclipse IDE, I can preview what my layout will look like. Did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Benju, at the bottom of the XML editor view pane in eclipse it has two tabs: Layout and foo.xml. Click on the Layout tab. For me, it doesn't always show what its supposed to. There is a tool called DroidDraw that attempts a similar service but isn't well maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I've noticed missing (still searching) is the ability to specify a custom debug key for your app.

If you haven't needed it yet, you probably don't care, but I need it because I work in a small team and share devices so signing with multiple keys becomes a pain since you have to uninstall every time you swap devices.
I've been searching for an hour with no results.

On the plus side, it's much more pleasant to work with and I love the Resharper style tips.